# Can Autobahn use a custom json encoder?

Tags: python, json, autobahn

When doing RPC with autobahn, autobahn supports procedures returning python objects as long as they are json serializable. Some objects I'd like to return are not by default json serializable. I can easily write a custom encoder, but how would autobahn know it needs to use it?

Comment: Could you show the code that sends an object that gets serialized with json? That would help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `_serialize` and `_unserialize` on your factories. See [here](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/master/autobahn/autobahn/wamp.py#L467). Please note that this API is (currently) not promised to be stable.